# Build a Laravel App With TDD - Episode 4, InvalidArgumentException: Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\Project]

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

I am deep in bug town here, can anyone help? 
I am following the tutorial line by line and have got as far as the unit test in the episode:
https://laracasts.com/series/build-a-laravel-app-with-tdd/episodes/4

I get the error:

> 1) Tests\Unit\ProjectTest::test_it_has_a_path
>   InvalidArgumentException: Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\Project].

Some info:

- The unit test is the second test in the video (starts @ 4:18), my
  code works fine for the first (feature) test, and the factory
  function works fine in tinker.
- I have tried all kinds of different filepaths for 'App\Project', and
  also tried static Project::class type references.
- My phpunit didn't run tests unless I prefixed the word 'test', even
  when filtering to the exact test name, so I believe this may be due
  to an underlying phpunit version difference.

My unit test:

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ProjectTest extends TestCase
{

    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function test_it_has_a_path()
    {
        $project = factory('App\Project')->create();
        $this->assertEquals('/project/' . $project->id, $this->path());
    }
}
```

My Project factory

```
/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\Project;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Project::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title' => $faker->sentence,
        'description' => $faker->sentence
    ];
});
```

My show method

```
public function show(Project $project)
    {
        return view('projects.show', compact('project'));
    }
```

My route

```
Route::get('projects/{project}', 'ProjectsController@show');
```

and the working feature test (for reference)

```
    public function test_a_user_can_view_a_project()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $project = factory('App\Project')->create();

        $this->get("/projects/" . $project->id)
            ->assertSee($project->title)
            ->assertSee($project->description);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried importing `App\Project` into your test and then calling `$project = factory(Project::class)->create();` ?

Comment: Yes I tried that too, it seems to have been a Laravel/ PHPUnit interaction error. Please see my answer below from Laracasts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this answer on the Laracasts forum that solved my problem:
the reason is because the unit test now extends from the PHPUnit testcase class instead of the framework testcase..

So you should avoid using factory in Unit tests. This was a change recently..

To be able to still use the factory, you should import this TestCase.

```
use Tests\TestCase;
```

And remove this:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
```

And here is the change:

```
https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/e30a0c979d98f2f1f7b6c565e4002734237a280b
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this - I wonder what the best practice is now if factories not supposed to be in tests by default..

Comment: I can hear Jeffrey in my head saying, 'Honestly, I think some developers are too picky about this, it's fine to have factories in your unit tests'